# Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: trigger

Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Raj_provider_detail_page: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a5fM00000000aMYIAY; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Raj_provider_detail_page: maximum trigger depth exceeded SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterInsert SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate SysConct_Provider_detail trigger event AfterUpdate: [] Trigger.Raj_provider_detail_page: line 85, column 1: []

```
trigger Raj_provider_detail_page on SysConct_Provider_detail__c (after insert,after Update) { 

map<string, SysConct_Password__c> userToCustomSetting = new map<string, SysConct_Password__c>();
    list<SysConct_Password__c> newSettings = new list<SysConct_Password__c>();
    Set<String> providerIds=new Set<String>();
    for (SysConct_Provider_detail__c stg : trigger.new){
        providerIds.add(stg.Id);
    }
    list<SysConct_Password__c> existingSettings = [SELECT  Id,Name,Password__c,AuthKey1__c,AuthKey2__c,ProviderID__c,MeterNumber__c,ProviderName__c,TransactionType__c  
                                                   FROM   SysConct_Password__c 
                                                   where Name In : providerIds];
    //  Notice the LIMIT above?  Without it, you'll probably receive a mark against you in your
    //  AppExchange Security Review findings report.  Queries need a WHERE or LIMIT


    //  Populate the map based on the above query's results - keyed by the Username (name contains username)               
    if (!existingSettings.isEmpty()){
        for (SysConct_Password__c s : existingSettings){
            userToCustomSetting.put(s.Name,s);
        }
    }

    for (SysConct_Provider_detail__c stg : trigger.new){
        if ((stg.SysConct_Password__c != null && stg.SysConct_Password__c  != '' )||(stg.SysConct_Transaction_Key__c != null && stg.SysConct_Transaction_Key__c != '')){

            SysConct_Password__c newPassword;
            if(!userToCustomSetting.containsKey(stg.Id)){
                newPassword=new SysConct_Password__c();
                newPassword.Name = string.valueof(stg.id);                  
                newPassword.MeterNumber__c = stg.SysConct_Meter_Number__c;
                newPassword.ProviderName__c = stg.SysConct_Provider_Name__c;
                newPassword.TransactionType__c = stg.SysConct_Transaction_Type__c;
                newPassword.ProviderID__c = stg.id;
                newPassword.Password__c = stg.SysConct_Password__c;

                if(stg.SysConct_Transaction_Key__c != null && stg.SysConct_Transaction_Key__c != ''){
                    string str1 = stg.SysConct_Transaction_Key__c;
                    if(str1.length()<256){
                        newPassword.AuthKey1__c = str1 ;
                    }else{
                        string str2 = str1.substring(0,244);
                        string str3 = str1.remove(str2);
                        newPassword.AuthKey1__c = str2;
                        newPassword.AuthKey2__c = str3;
                    }                        
                }
                newSettings.add(newPassword);                   
            }else{                    
                newPassword = userToCustomSetting.get(stg.Id);
            boolean ischangeKey=false;
                if (stg.SysConct_Password__c != newPassword.Password__c){
                    newPassword.Password__c = stg.SysConct_Password__c;
                    ischangeKey=true;
                }if(stg.SysConct_Transaction_Key__c != newPassword.AuthKey1__c+newPassword.AuthKey2__c){
                    string str1 = stg.SysConct_Transaction_Key__c;
                    if(str1.length()<256){
                        newPassword.AuthKey1__c = str1 ;
                    }else{
                        string str2 = str1.substring(0,244);
                        string str3 = str1.remove(str2);
                        newPassword.AuthKey1__c = str2;
                        newPassword.AuthKey2__c = str3;
                    } 
                    ischangeKey=true;                   
                }
                if(ischangeKey)
                    newSettings.add(newPassword);

            }
        }
    }
    if (!newSettings.isEmpty()){
        system.debug('newSettings====='+newSettings);
        upsert newSettings;
        list<SysConct_Provider_detail__c> validApplicationSettings = new list<SysConct_Provider_detail__c>();
        for(SysConct_Password__c password : newSettings){
            SysConct_Provider_detail__c stg=new SysConct_Provider_detail__c(Id=password.Name);
            if(password.Password__c != null && password.Password__c !=  '')
                stg.SysConct_Password__c = '************';
            if(password.AuthKey1__c != null && password.AuthKey1__c  != '')
                stg.SysConct_Transaction_Key__c = '**************';
            validApplicationSettings.add(stg);
        }
        if(!validApplicationSettings.isEmpty())
            update validApplicationSettings;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `AuthKey1__c`  to the query

Use this

```
list<SysConct_Password__c> existingSettings =

 [SELECT 

id,Name,Password__c,ProviderID__c,AuthKey1__c,MeterNumber__c,ProviderName__c,TransactionType__c  


FROM   SysConct_Password__c

 where Name In : providerIds];
```